# Insert object into MongoDB wso2 Data service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

```
<query id="mongo_insert" useConfig="fetchmongo">
      <expression>device_attributes.insert("{
    "deviceId": #,
    "vin": #,
        "clusterDetails.provisioned": #,
        "clusterDetails.sbEndpoint": #,
        "clusterDetails.clusterName": #,
        "clusterDetails.clusterId": #,
        "clusterDetails.nbEndpoint": #,
        "clusterDetails.kubeMaster": #,
        "clusterDetails.status": #
}")</expression>
      <param name="deviceId" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
      <param name="vin" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="provisioned" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="sbEndpoint" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="clusterName" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="clusterId" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="nbEndpoint" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="kubeMaster" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="status" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
```

this is my query to insert the data into MongoDB data service. My payload is having object like this trying to insert json its not working so i converted into xml and trying to insert.but its not taking the values object inside object. how to read those values in query

```
{
    "deviceId": 11111,
    "vin": "WRTHRKSHS0000011",
    "clusterDetails": {
        "provisioned": "N",
        "sbEndpoint": "192.168.22.22",
        "clusterName": "clustertwo",
        "clusterId": "cluster11",
        "nbEndpoint": "192.168.22.22",
        "kubeMaster": "192.168.22.22",
        "status": "D"
    }
}
```

And XML object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <deviceId>111111</deviceId>
    <vin>WERTRKSHS0000011</vin>
    <clusterDetails>
        <provisioned>N</provisioned>
        <sbEndpoint>192.168.22.22</sbEndpoint>
        <clusterName>clustertwo</clusterName>
        <clusterId>cluster10</clusterId>
        <nbEndpoint>192.168.22.22</nbEndpoint>
        <kubeMaster>192.168.22.22</kubeMaster>
        <status>D</status>
    </clusterDetails>
</root>
```

this payload i am giving in body
error i am getting[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation of data services, only the first-level data is read to extract the parameters, In your case since you have `provisioned` as an inner value, the DSS won't be able to extract it. You can follow one of the following to fix your issue,

**Option 1**: If possible change the request structure so all the data are in the same first level as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <deviceId>111111</deviceId>
    <vin>WERTRKSHS0000011</vin>
    <provisioned>N</provisioned>
    <sbEndpoint>192.168.22.22</sbEndpoint>
    <clusterName>clustertwo</clusterName>
    <clusterId>cluster10</clusterId>
    <nbEndpoint>192.168.22.22</nbEndpoint>
    <kubeMaster>192.168.22.22</kubeMaster>
    <status>D</status>
</root>
```

**Option 2**: Use the `dataServiceCall` mediator to call the DSS

1. To use the you need an operation to the Dataservice as follows,

```xml
<operation name="mongo_insert_op" returnRequestStatus="true">
    <call-query href="mongo_insert">
        <with-param name="deviceId" query-param="deviceId"/>
        <with-param name="vin" query-param="vin"/>
        <with-param name="provisioned" query-param="provisioned"/>
        <with-param name="sbEndpoint" query-param="sbEndpoint"/>
        <with-param name="clusterName" query-param="clusterName"/>
        <with-param name="clusterId" query-param="clusterId"/>
        <with-param name="nbEndpoint" query-param="nbEndpoint"/>
        <with-param name="kubeMaster" query-param="kubeMaster"/>
        <with-param name="status" query-param="status"/>
    </call-query>
</operation>
```

2. Create an API to front the DSS and expose it to the clients. You may need to set the `serviceName` and the `operation` name accordingly.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/mongoDSS_API" name="mongoDSS_API" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <dataServiceCall serviceName="ADD_YOUR_DSS_NAME_HERE">
                <operations type="single">
                    <operation name="mongo_insert_op">
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.deviceId" name="deviceId"/>
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.vin" name="vin"/>
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.clusterDetails.provisioned" name="provisioned"/>
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.clusterDetails.sbEndpoint" name="sbEndpoint"/>
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.clusterDetails.clusterName" name="clusterName"/>
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.clusterDetails.clusterId" name="clusterId"/>
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.clusterDetails.nbEndpoint" name="nbEndpoint"/>
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.clusterDetails.kubeMaster" name="kubeMaster"/>
                        <param evaluator="json" expression="$.clusterDetails.status" name="status"/>
                    </operation>
                </operations>
                <source type="inline"/>
                <target type="body"/>
            </dataServiceCall>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

For more information,

- [Data Service Call Mediator](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/dss-mediator/)